# CSS breaking website

Tags: css

I have the following code for a 'bouncy' page transition, but every time it's not commented out, the entire CSS breaks. It didn't do this before I changed some of the keyframes, but now I broke it lol :(

Any help?

```
 body {
    -webkit-animation-name: scalein;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 750ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: scalein;
    -moz-animation-duration: 750ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: scalein;
    animation-duration: 750ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes scalein {
  1% { 
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  39% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  85% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scalein {
  1% { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  39% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  85% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes scalein {
  1% { 
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  39% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  75% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  85% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes scalein {
  1% { 
    -o-transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  39% {
    -o-transform: scale(1.3);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  75% {
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  85% {
    -o-transform: scale(0.9;
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error, you forgot the closing parenthesis:

```
@-o-keyframes scalein {
    ...
    -o-transform: scale(0.9;
    ...
}
```

Comment: How did I not notice that?! Thank you!